# Weblogic error (Application Server)

Tags: java, weblogic

I am trying to start an app server but am getting an error. Please help me with the same. Below is the log of the same;

```
"Timer-0" id=15 idx=0x3c tid=2632 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: java/util/TaskQueue@0x010AFBD0[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java/util/TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:483)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: java/util/TaskQueue@0x010AFBD0[fat lock]
    at java/util/TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"Timer-1" id=16 idx=0x40 tid=2628 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: java/util/TaskQueue@0x013710A8[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=17 idx=0x44 tid=2268 prio=5 alive, in native, wa
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x01376050[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:157)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x01376050[fat lock]
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=18 idx=0x48 tid=1028 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x013C49B0[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x013C49B0[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=19 idx=0x4c tid=1720 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x013C5090[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x013C5090[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=20 idx=0x50 tid=2788 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x013C5770[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x013C5770[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=21 idx=0x54 tid=2808 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x013C5E50[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x013C5E50[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=22 idx=0x58 tid=1904 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A66EF8[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A66EF8[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=23 idx=0x5c tid=968 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A675D8[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A675D8[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=24 idx=0x60 tid=3260 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A67CB8[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A67CB8[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '7' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=25 idx=0x64 tid=1948 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A68398[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A68398[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=26 idx=0x68 tid=3404 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A68A78[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A68A78[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=27 idx=0x6c tid=3420 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A69158[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A69158[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=28 idx=0x70 tid=3356 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A69838[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A69838[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=29 idx=0x74 tid=3692 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A69F18[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A69F18[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=30 idx=0x78 tid=1604 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A6A5F8[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A6A5F8[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=31 idx=0x7c tid=3444 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A6ACD8[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A6ACD8[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=32 idx=0x80 tid=2152 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A6B3B8[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A6B3B8[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=33 idx=0x84 tid=3448 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A58B8[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A58B8[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '16' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=34 idx=0x88 tid=3352 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A5F98[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A5F98[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '17' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=35 idx=0x8c tid=3108 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A6678[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A6678[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=36 idx=0x90 tid=3452 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A6D58[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A6D58[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '19' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=37 idx=0x94 tid=3348 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A7438[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A7438[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '20' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=38 idx=0x98 tid=2020 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A7B18[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A7B18[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '21' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=39 idx=0x9c tid=3456 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A81F8[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A81F8[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=40 idx=0xa0 tid=3460 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A88D8[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A88D8[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '23' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=41 idx=0xa4 tid=852 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A8FB8[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A8FB8[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"ExecuteThread: '24' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=42 idx=0xa8 tid=3468 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A9698[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:91)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x016A9698[fat lock]
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:115)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"weblogic.time.TimeEventGenerator" id=43 idx=0xac tid=3240 prio=9 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/time/common/internal/TimeTable@0x02668018[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at weblogic/time/common/internal/TimeTable.snooze(TimeTable.java:286)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/time/common/internal/TimeTable@0x02668018[fat lock]
    at weblogic/time/common/internal/TimeEventGenerator.run(TimeEventGenerator.java:117)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"JMAPI event thread" id=44 idx=0xb0 tid=3464 prio=5 alive, in native, native_waiting, daemon

"weblogic.timers.TimerThread" id=45 idx=0xb4 tid=3488 prio=9 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/timers/internal/TimerThread@0x01398390[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at weblogic/timers/internal/TimerThread$Thread.run(TimerThread.java:267)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/timers/internal/TimerThread@0x01398390[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=46 idx=0xb8 tid=3484 prio=5 alive, in native, wa
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x02668498[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:157)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x02668498[fat lock]
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"Thread-7" id=49 idx=0xbc tid=2196 prio=5 alive, in native, parked, daemon
    -- Parking to wait for: java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@0x02669128
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.park0(J)V(Native Method)
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.park(Locks.java:2517)
    at sun/misc/Unsafe.park(ZJ)V(Native Method)
    at java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
    at java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1925)
    at java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:358)
    at weblogic/utils/concurrent/JDK15ConcurrentBlockingQueue.take(JDK15ConcurrentBlockingQueue.java:89)
    at weblogic/store/internal/PersistentStoreImpl.getOutstandingWork(PersistentStoreImpl.java:567)
    at weblogic/store/internal/PersistentStoreImpl.run(PersistentStoreImpl.java:615)
    at weblogic/store/internal/PersistentStoreImpl$2.run(PersistentStoreImpl.java:383)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"VDE Transaction Processor Thread" id=52 idx=0xc0 tid=3888 prio=2 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: com/octetstring/vde/backend/standard/TransactionProcessor@0x01014498[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at com/octetstring/vde/backend/standard/TransactionProcessor.waitChange(TransactionProcessor.java:367)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: com/octetstring/vde/backend/standard/TransactionProcessor@0x01014498[fat lock]
    at com/octetstring/vde/backend/standard/TransactionProcessor.run(TransactionProcessor.java:212)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"DoSManager" id=55 idx=0xc8 tid=3896 prio=6 alive, in native, sleeping, native_waiting, daemon
    at java/lang/Thread.sleep(J)V(Native Method)
    at com/octetstring/vde/DoSManager.run(DoSManager.java:433)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=56 idx=0xcc tid=1032 prio=5 alive, in native, da
    at bea/jmapi/DiagnosticCommandImpl.execute(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;)V(Native Method)
    at bea/jmapi/DiagnosticCommandImpl.execute(DiagnosticCommandImpl.java:50)
    at com/bea/jvm/DiagnosticCommand.execute(DiagnosticCommand.java:242)
    at com/bea/jvm/DiagnosticCommand$Command.execute(DiagnosticCommand.java:394)
    at bea/jmapi/ThreadSystemImpl.getThreadStackDump(ThreadSystemImpl.java:98)
    at weblogic/platform/JRockitVM.threadDump(JRockitVM.java:61)
    at weblogic/t3/srvr/T3Srvr.logThreadDump(T3Srvr.java:280)
    at weblogic/t3/srvr/T3Srvr.failed(T3Srvr.java:207)
    ^-- Holding lock: weblogic/t3/srvr/T3Srvr@0x00C0DC20[fat lock]
    at weblogic/health/HealthMonitorService$2.run(HealthMonitorService.java:188)
    at weblogic/work/SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516)
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"Thread-11" id=57 idx=0xd0 tid=4008 prio=5 alive, in native, parked, daemon
    -- Parking to wait for: java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@0x0204C278
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.park0(J)V(Native Method)
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.park(Locks.java:2517)
    at sun/misc/Unsafe.park(ZJ)V(Native Method)
    at java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
    at java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1925)
    at java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:358)
    at weblogic/utils/concurrent/JDK15ConcurrentBlockingQueue.take(JDK15ConcurrentBlockingQueue.java:89)
    at weblogic/store/internal/PersistentStoreImpl.getOutstandingWork(PersistentStoreImpl.java:567)
    at weblogic/store/internal/PersistentStoreImpl.run(PersistentStoreImpl.java:615)
    at weblogic/store/internal/PersistentStoreImpl$2.run(PersistentStoreImpl.java:383)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=58 idx=0xd4 tid=2656 prio=5 alive, in native, wa
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x0255D8D8[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:157)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x0255D8D8[fat lock]
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"OracleTimeoutPollingThread" id=59 idx=0xd8 tid=1852 prio=10 alive, in native, sleeping, native_waiting, daemon
    at java/lang/Thread.sleep(J)V(Native Method)
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleTimeoutPollingThread.run(OracleTimeoutPollingThread.java:150)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"Thread-12" id=60 idx=0xdc tid=3568 prio=5 alive, in native, parked, daemon
    -- Parking to wait for: java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@0x01090770
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.park0(J)V(Native Method)
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.park(Locks.java:2517)
    at sun/misc/Unsafe.park(ZJ)V(Native Method)
    at java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
    at java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1925)
    at java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:358)
    at weblogic/utils/concurrent/JDK15ConcurrentBlockingQueue.take(JDK15ConcurrentBlockingQueue.java:89)
    at weblogic/store/internal/PersistentStoreImpl.getOutstandingWork(PersistentStoreImpl.java:567)
    at weblogic/store/internal/PersistentStoreImpl.run(PersistentStoreImpl.java:615)
    at weblogic/store/internal/PersistentStoreImpl$2.run(PersistentStoreImpl.java:383)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(IIIII)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
```

Comment: This is not an error stack trace, this is a thread dump which shows lot of threads waiting for requests. Does the server not start up at all?

Comment: Wouldn't this best be asked on http://serverfault.com/ instead of here?

Comment: Just a guess: make sure your Oracle DB is working correctly: some of threads in the dump may suggest the server is waiting for the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things look odd here:

```
"ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'snet.app.executeQueue'" id=27 idx=0x6c tid=3420 prio=5 alive, in native, waiting, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/kernel/ServerExecuteThread@0x01A69158[fat lock]
```

This looks like an application that is deployed to WebLogic isn't doing something right.  It is holding a Fat Lock waiting for something...

and:

```
"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=56 idx=0xcc tid=1032 prio=5 alive, in native, da
    at bea/jmapi/DiagnosticCommandImpl.execute(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;)V(Native Method)
    at bea/jmapi/DiagnosticCommandImpl.execute(DiagnosticCommandImpl.java:50)
```

This looks like it is using the WLDF to write a file and dump information to disk.  Are you using WLDF?  If so look at hte configuration and try disabling it to see if the problem goes away.

The other waits look fine - if you have a pool of threads that are not doing anything then of course they will be waiting for a notification that there is something to do.

Another thing to look at doing is 1) ensuring that all sessions are closed to all applications or enable 'Ignore Sessions on Shutdown' on the Server in the Admin Console.  If these don't work, please post the actual error.